# Problems with data from django to html

Tags: html, django, django-views

My goal is to have the sum of elements in `lista[]` but gives me this error. `lista[]` is composed of decimal numbers

```
ValueError at /
    argument must be a sequence of length 3
```

My code :

#### views.py

```py
def Home(request):
    assets = Post.objects.filter(Asset="BTC", Utente="1").values_list('Quantit')
    lista = []
    for asset in assets:
        lista.append(asset)
    somma = sum(Decimal(lista))
    return render(request, 'porttrack/home.html', {'lista': lista})
```

#### models.py

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    Utente = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Asset = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    Quantit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=11)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

by printing out only `lista[]` without `somma`, it's show a list like that:

```
    [(Decimal('0.01000000000'),), (Decimal('0.01000000000'),), (Decimal('0.01000000000'),), 
    (Decimal('0.01000000000'),), (Decimal('0.01000000000'),), (Decimal('0.01000000000'),), 
    (Decimal('1.00000000000'),), (Decimal('1.00000000000'),), (Decimal('1.00000000000'),), 
    (Decimal('1.00000000000'),), (Decimal('1.00000000000'),)]
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Queryset method values_list returns tuples by default so your `lista` is not a list of decimals *Decimal('0.01')*. It is a list of 1-tuples *(Decimal('0.01'),)* and you can't sum those.

Add **flat=True** parameter to values_list call to get a list of single values instead of 1-tuples.

```
assets = Post.objects.filter(Asset="BTC", Utente="1").values_list('Quantit', flat=True)
lista = list(assets)
somma = sum(lista)
```